# what is the difference between "Cuda Device" and GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I read one tutorial about CUDA on this link.

```
http://geco.mines.edu/tesla/cuda_tutorial_mio/index.html
```

In this tutorial, It calls "CUDA Device". What is a "CUDA Device"? Is every GPU is a "CUDA Device" and vice verse ?? if not, please name one "CUDA Device"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "CUDA device" is a single unit device that can support CUDA. In theory it can be anything; I am surprised that there are no efficient CUDA-on-CPU drivers yet :(
However, currently, the only devices that do so are NVIDIA GPUs starting from GF8000 series.

Do note however, that dual-cards (e.g. GTX690) provide two CUDA devices.

Answer (score 0):

CUDA devices are nVidia devices that supports CUDA. Not every GPU is a CUDA device. I don't know if every CUDA device is a GPU, it might be, or not. AMD GPUs for example do not support CUDA, but they support OpenCL.

Answer (score 0):

CUDA device means CUDA-enabled devices. It can be a CUDA-enabled GPU also or some other device. For more information on CUDA devices go to this: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus